# Changing Page Number Style without Fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I want to change the page numbering of my document to say "Page # of ##" instead of just "#". The `fancyhdr` package appears to change a lot, and it seem unfortunate to have to import it for one small thing.

Comment: What do you have at the moment? Please show us a short compilable code ...

Answer (score 2):

For the last page you'll always want to

```
\usepackage{lastpage}
```

This gives you

```
\pageref{LastPage}
```

which will put in the last page of your document.
After that it depends on your class:

### KOMA

Using `KOMA` this is quite easy:

```
\renewcommand\pagemark{\usekomafont{pagenumber}Page \thepage of \pageref{LastPage}}
```

### Base classes

Using a base class, e.g. `article`, one needs a little more work. I would recommend to create a new style based on the plain (or headings) style and use this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\let\ps@mystyle\ps@plain % Copy the plain style to mystyle
\patchcmd{\ps@mystyle}{\thepage}{Page\ \thepage\ of\ \pageref{LastPage}}{}{} % replace number by desired string
\makeatother


\title{test}
\pagestyle{mystyle}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle\thispagestyle{mystyle}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Note that `\maketitle` (if not using `book`) uses `\thispagestyle{plain}`. That's why you have to override it manually. If you do use the `book` class, you need to do the same after `\chapter`. Also don't forget to use `\pagestyle` to declare a default page style, even if you want it to be `plain`.

### Memoir

In `memoir`, you can easily use

```
\makeevenfoot{pagestyle}{left}{center}{right}
\makeoddfoot{pagestyle}{}{}{}
\makeevenhead{pagestyle}{}{}{}
\makeoddhead{pagestyle}{}{}{}
```

and use your desired `Page\ \thepage\ of\ \thelastpage` in the corresponding brackets. You can copy a style, to create your own from it, by

```
\copypagestyle{mystyle}{headings}
```

`memoir` is an exception, regarding loading `lastpage` or an equivalent. It provides `\thelastpage` already.