# Replace pagenumber for one page in scrbook

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, page-numbering, scrbook

I have a two sided scrbook where I want to replace one single page number with a special char, while the rest of the pages should remain numbered with arabic numbers. How can I achieve this?

So far I have tried it with `fancyhdr` and with redefining `\pagemark` as you can see in the MWEs, but both did not bring the intended result.

With `fancyhdr` the pagenumber resp. rfoot is not put in the same place as for the normal scrbook style since I use `mpinclude=true`:

```
\documentclass[twoside,mpinclude=true]{scrbook}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Book}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\lfoot[{:-)}]{}
\rfoot[]{{:-)}}
\cfoot{}
\section*{Acknowledgements}
I want to thank everyone.

\clearpage
\pagestyle{plain}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I redefined `\pagemark` it is in the right place but I do not know, how to reset it to the previous definition.

```
\documentclass[twoside,mpinclude=true]{scrbook}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Book}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum[3]

\clearpage

\renewcommand{\pagemark}{:-)}
\section*{Acknowledgements}
I want to thank everyone.

\clearpage
\pagestyle{plain}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fond an answer to the second option by redefining pagemark in this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/439431/11820

`\pagemark` has to be reset to `\renewcommand\pagemark{\usekomafont{pagenumber}\thepage}`.

```
\documentclass[twoside,mpinclude=true]{scrbook}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Book}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum[3]

\clearpage

\renewcommand{\pagemark}{:-)}
\section*{Acknowledgements}
I want to thank everyone.

\clearpage
\renewcommand\pagemark{\usekomafont{pagenumber}\thepage}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

**Note:** I would not mind also receiving an answer to correctly place the pagenumber with fancyhdr in conjunction with koma scrbook `mpinclude=true`.